# Getting Conversion Error in Beyond Compare

Tags: java, class, jar, openjdk-11, beyondcompare3

I'm facing an issue while comparing two jar files. Getting conversion error while trying to compare two class files inside the jar files.

I've tried changing encoding type in File formats and it didn't resolve the issue. Also downloaded the required plugins to decompile the class files.

Please help me out in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare's [Java class to source file format](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=kb_moreformatsv4) uses [JAD](https://varaneckas.com/jad/) to decompile .class files to .java source. It's a pretty old decompiler, so it doesn't support .class files that use newer java features.

As a workaround, use a newer decompiler to extract .class files to .java source outside of Beyond Compare, then compare the .java files in Beyond Compare.